# How to make two line draw on 1 chart? now it will create 1 blue line chart, then create anther chart with 2 lines

Tags: r, plot, line

How to make two line draw on 1 chart?  now it will create 1 blue line chart, then create anther chart with 2 lines.

```
par(mfrow=c(4,2))
# chart 1
plot(comparingplot_cl[,1], type = "l", col = "blue")

lines(comparingplot_cl[,5], type = "l", col = "red")

# chart 2
plot(comparingplot_cl[,2], type = "l", col = "blue")

lines(comparingplot_cl[,6], type = "l", col = "red")

# chart 3
plot(comparingplot_cl[,3], type = "l", col = "blue")

lines(comparingplot_cl[,7], type = "l", col = "red")

# chart 4
plot(comparingplot_cl[,4], type = "l", col = "blue")

lines(comparingplot_cl[,8], type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: You have 4 plots but a grid of 8 plots, `mfrow=c(4,2)`.